# Deploying Control Adapters in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, moss, customization

Is there any way to automatically deploy Control Adapters (some menu modifications) in SharePoint using WSP solution and features ? Can I programmatically edit/deploy some ".browser" file?

If it is not possible what are the alternatives (some good practice) ?

I need this for Publishing site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, with Features you always have the ability to define a FeatureReceiver which basically is callout to a developer provided assembly for handing Feature lifecycle events (e.e. onFeatureInstalled, onFeatureActivated, etc.)  There you would be able to write .Net code to interact with the infrastructure.

Comment: You think that I should, inside Feature, write bare .NET code and put file in the physical folder ? Maybe it is worth a try if I can get full path within the Feature.

Comment: I think you should be able to get the applications folder via the SharePoint object model as you know to which application your feature was deployed to.

Comment: This is publishing site and will have to deploy to two virtual folders (FBA) :(. But maybe I could manage it also.

Answer (score 1):

you could give [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) a chance. It's a open source tool pack SharePoint solutions. I know with WSPBuilder you cloud definitely deploy files into the bin and resource folder within an application's directory (...\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80).

So perhaps it is also possible to deploy files into the App_Browsers folder. I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article](http://blog.mikehacker.net/2009/10/25/using-a-control-adapter-for-branding-part-3/) explaining this task. Your can add method like this to your master page class:

```
private static void AddControlAdapterToType<T>(Type controlType) where T : ControlAdapter, new()
   {
       if (controlType == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("controlType", "This argument can not be null!");
       }

       var adapters = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Adapters;
       var key = controlType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
       if (!adapters.Contains(key))
       {
           var adapter = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
           adapters.Add(key, adapter);
       }
   }
```

And then you call it from the Master Page constructor like this:

```
AddControlAdapterToType<YourCustomAdapter>(typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart));
```